# make a soapui mock REST service that can return a 429 status code

Tags: soapui

I have SoapUI (free) v5.4.0.

I need to implement a mock service that returns a 429 (too many requests) status code.  It appears that the mockservice allows me to set the response status code, but I can only select it from a dropdown, and 429 is not one of the options.  How can I customize the mock service to return a truly custom value instead of one of the values from the dropdown?

**Update**:

I tried changing the mock action from "Sequence" to "Script".  I then tried a very simple script, like the following:

```
mockRequest.httpResponse.status = 429
```

I then click the Play button, which when I was using "Sequence", this would just start the listener and wait for requests to come in.  Instead, when I clicked the Play button, it immediately failed with:

```
com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.DispatchException: Failed to dispatch
using script; java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 
'httpResponse' on null object
```

I then added a line like the following before this line:

```
log.info("mockRequest[" + mockRequest + "]")
```

When I clicked Play again, it printed this in the script log:

```
Sat Jan 18 08:53:24 PST 2020:INFO:mockRequest[null]
```

I am obviously missing some basic details in the setup of this.

Comment: You may use `Script Dispath` to achieve the same.

Comment: I assume what you meant was "script dispatch". However, I need more information.  By walking down the object tree and looking at all the options, I was able to find that one of the options on the mock actions was to change the dispatch type from sequence to script, and the text box showed some simple examples, but I need more information about what I can do in that box.

Comment: scrpt would run on receiving the request.this is basically let us do what we want on the request and send the response the way we wanted with programming.

Answer (score 1):

Add a response to the mock service to return 429 error code. I named the response as 'Response 429'. In the script section of 'Response 429' set the http status.

```
mockResponse.setResponseHttpStatus(429)
```

I had other mock scenarios to test response having http status code as 200 and 500. I used the query param 'returnCode' to get different responses. The following script to the mockService GET method did the job.

```
def returnCode = mockRequest.getRequest().getParameter("returnCode")
 
if( returnCode.equals("429"))
{   
    return "Response 429"
}
else if( returnCode.equals("500"))
{   
    return "Response 500"
}    
else {
    return "Response 200"
}
```

I am posting the response even though this is an old question. It might be of use to someone else.

Comment: In my post, you'll notice that when I printed "mockRequest", it was null. That leads me to believe that "mockResponse" will also be null. I imagine this has something to do with the higher-level configuration of this mock server, but I don't know what that would be.